# How to scrape Bitcoin prices from GDAX using web sockets so that the value changes in real-time?

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

So currently I'm going to the GDAX website to scrape the bitcoin price every second (using the requests library for python). A friend said that I'm making too many requests and may get IP banned. I learned about WebSockets and real-time changes. I was wondering, can someone help me make a simple code to get real-time change of this element:

```
<span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs">6,515.49 USD</span>
```

from this [GDAX site](https://www.gdax.com/trade/BTC-USD)? (the current price is $6,515.49, that's why that number is in the element).

I'm currently learning web sockets and it will take me a long time to get learned enough of it to start writing the code. Thank you guys, i really need help with this

EDIT:
I tried their API but idk how to use it, idk how to get the BTC to USD number.I GET NUMBERS CLOSE TO THE PRICE BUT not quiet. here what i have so far:
from this [site](https://docs.gdax.com/?javascript#introduction)

```
<html>
<script>
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.gdax.com");

ws.onopen = function(){
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        "type": "unsubscribe",
        "product_ids": [
            "BTC-USD"
        ],
        "channels": ["ticker"]
    }) 
};

ws.onmessage = function(msg){
  var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
  console.log(response);
};
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you referred to their API? What have you tried to far ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Python solution, but rather an Excel solution.  I'm posting this, because I din't see anyone post anything for you as of yet.  I think this will do what you want, at least until you find the exact solution you are seeking out.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim html        As Object
    Dim tbl         As Object
    Dim tRow        As Object
    Dim tCel        As Object
    Dim x           As Long
    Dim y           As Long

    With CreateObject("MSxml2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/", False
        .send
        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each tbl In html.getElementsByTagName("table")
        For Each tRow In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each tCel In tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                y = y + 1
                Cells(x + 1, y) = tCel.innerText
            Next tCel
            y = 0
            x = x + 1
        Next tRow
    Next tbl
End Sub
```